# Powershell Regex and Splitting a String

Tags: .net, regex, string, powershell

I have a column in a database table that I must convert to a comma delimited list (because I will be inserting each item in the list as a new record in a new table). Show below are some examples of the data.

Example data:

- 5209291 5847149,8943073, 8943895, 8963839
- 3215874,2435245,2345563,634523,jim,jake,henry, school of health professions

My requirements:

- The list must only be numbers
- the list must only be delimited by commas

A perfect solution using the example above would be:

- 5209291,5847149,8943073,8943895,8963839
- 3215874,2435245,2345563,634523

What I've done so far is use String Split and hardcode the delimiters by passing them into the method. This is not going to work because every day I get a feed from the DBA and the delimiter could potentially be anything. I wish I could provide something that show "what I've done" but I'm just really at a loss here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match sequence of digits by this regular expression: `\d+`. All you need is to match each sequence of digits in input string and join them by comma.

```
[regex]::Matches($InputString,'\d+')-join','
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly.